# Size of 2 dimensional ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have always found this to be problematic, essentially a guaranteed null pointer in most cases.

Say we have a two dimensional ArrayList, like so:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> outer;
```

Now, I want to get the dimensions of the inner arrays (we assume that they should all be the same size).

I often find that I do this:

```
int width = outer.size();
int length = outer.get(0).size();
```

but this is inherently unsafe and just horrible. What is a better way to do this?

One better idea would be to iterate through all the array elements in the outer array, find the size of each inner array, make sure the sizes are all the same value, and then return that value, but that's a bit intensive.

Something like this:

```
  private int getSizeOfInner(){

    int size = null;

    for(ArrayList<Integer> a: outer){
         if(size == null){
             size = a.size();
          }
         else{
             if(a.size() != size){
              throw new Exception("Inconsistent inner array sizes");
            }

          }
       }
     return size;
    }
```

this seems pretty much overkill for this type of problem...

Comment: For what type of problem? Why are you creating `List`(s) of `List`(s) in the first place?

Comment: think of it as Integer[][] but with variable sizes.

Comment: If the assumption is that the inner lists all have the same size and type then you should enforce that by making it an array type and not an array list, which is meant to have variable length.

Comment: Sure, but is there a "prettier" way of getting the inner size other than outer[0].length?

Comment: The value is dynamic. How do you find a dynamic value without evaluating it in the first place? Which size are you looking for? Are you looking for the size at a specific index or are you looking for the sum of all of the sizes of the inner list?

Comment: `Integer[][]` does not guarantee uniformity of inner array sizes.  The question is really who do you want enforcing the size of inner lists?  Maybe your `getSizeOfInner` assumes it, but your mutators should enforce it.  Also, generally, declare your variables as `List` rather than `ArrayList`.

Comment: Since all the inner arrays should be the same length/size, I want to find that out, later in the program. The simplest way to do that would be to grab the zeroeth element of the outer array and find that length/size but that seems very inelegant.

Comment: If you are asking for a built in method then no there isn't a prettier method. Iteration is probably your best bet. What if outer[0] doesn't get filled but the others do? Then you are stuck with the issue I'm sure you've already thought of (incorrect length).

Comment: Use a flat array of size `width` * `height` and do simple index math to access element with `x + width * y`.

Comment: What is the context of the problem you are trying to solve? A list of lists is vague. Why do you need that? Maybe there is a design issue here. Is there a better way to implement the data?

Comment: I agree with other commentors : _"Since all the inner arrays should be the same length/size, I want to find that out, later in the program."_ ... You shouldn't _have_ to check on that; you should _enforce_ it.  Maybe that means writing a "Grid" class to handle it.  One of the original, founding, fundamental principles behind Object-Oriented programming is that you _**can't**_ put an object in an invalid state, because your constructors and mutator methods should enforce validity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> int length = outer.get(0).size();
> ```
>
> but this is inherently unsafe and just horrible. What is a better way
>   to do this?

Not sure what you mean by horrible. However, this is what I would do:

```
int length = outer.get(0) == null ? 0 : outer.get(0).size();
```

Answer (score 2):

i am presuming here collection outer will not be null

```
int width = outer.size();
int length = CollectionUtils.size(outer.get(0))
```

CollectionUtils is a class from Apache API

[org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils] .

it is safe and reliable.